# How to update Timestamp Column where value is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to '2020-01-01 11:28:47'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update Timestamp field value to some expired date and want to set it
where values are '0000-00-00 00:00:00' But my query is not working. I have tried lot of solutions from stack overflow but none of them works

Here is my MySql Command

```
update users set `subscribe_at` = '2020-01-01 11:28:47' AND `subscription_valid_upto` = '2020-01-01 11:28:47'
WHERE `device_type` = 'I' AND `subscribe_at` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND subscription_valid_upto = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Which works without errors but nothing happens , i have checked warnings and it says

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2020-01-01 11:28:47'
```

Here is my Table Data and its Structure.

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use a comma to separate columns to be updated not and

Comment: Consult the [MySQL UPDATE Statement documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), taking note of *assignment_list*.

Comment: `set  'subscribe_at' = '2020-01-01 11:28:47' ,'subscription_valid_upto' = '2020-01-01 11:28:47'`

Comment: @P.Salmon Can you give me example ?

Comment: in `SET` you need to separate field with comma(`,`) instead of `AND`

Comment: The manual is full of examples..and you could search for mysql update multiple fields..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
SET subscribe_at = CASE WHEN subscribe_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                        THEN '2020-01-01 11:28:47'
                        ELSE subscribe_at
                        END, 
    subscription_valid_upto = CASE WHEN subscription_valid_upto = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                                   THEN '2020-01-01 11:28:47'
                                   ELSE subscription_valid_upto 
                                   END
WHERE device_type = 'I' 
  AND (    subscribe_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
        OR subscription_valid_upto = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. i will accept this shortly..! @Akina Can you explain about the issue and how did you came up with solution ?

Comment: @OnkarMusale The problem was in: 1)  you have ignored the syntax 2) you have not paid attention to operators precedence 3) the logic created had not matched to needed one.

Comment: I realised my mistake, it was silly, i used AND instead of comma, below query works fine, why you camp up with above large query ? update users set `subscribe_at` = '2019-01-10 10:10:10',`subscription_valid_upto` = '2019-01-10 10:10:10' 
WHERE `device_type` = 'I' AND `subscribe_at` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND `subscription_valid_upto` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: @OnkarMusale I have provided a case where only one of the two fields has the value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' - you have not claimed that it is impossible.